# Installing ios app via link on any device (Without knowing the udid of the device)?

Tags: ios, iphone

i saw this guys where able to do it
https://virginia.dov-e.com/bridge/download_powerade.html.
Please check the above link from your iphone
opening this link from any ios device will access you to install the app.
with no udid\account and other stuff..

anyone know how is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.diawi.com/

Upload your ipa here and it will give you a link and then you can use that link to install the app on your iphone and you can also share it with anyone.

the ipa should be signed with distribution profile.

Diawi is a tool for iOS developers to deploy Development and Ad hoc iOS applications directly to the device.

1. Upload the application and its provisioning profile.
2. Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself.
3. Open the link in Safari on the iOS device and click on install

Comment: Thanks, is it without the need of enterprise membership ?

Comment: you do not need the enterprise membership for that but the udid of the target devices must be added in the developer account for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could do this. You need [enterprise membership](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). Then you could distribute your to **any** device with some 3rd party like [Hockey App](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) by making your app public and just distributing your public download link. I've done this numerous times without any problems!

NB: I'm not sure about [Apple's TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) but it probably has similar capabilities as Hockey App.